# Cloud Functions for Firebase killed due to memory limit exceeded

Tags: firebase, memory-management, google-cloud-functions

I keep getting a sporadic error from Cloud Functions for Firebase when converting a relatively small image (2mb). When successful, the function only takes about 2000ms or less to finish, and according to Image Magick documentation should I should not see any problems.

I tried increasing the buffer size for the command, which isn't allows from within Firebase, and I tried to find alternatives to `.spawn()` as that could be overloaded with garbage and slow things down. Nothing works.

Comment: All the info is here: [manage-functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions).

Comment: More specifically, here: [#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation)

Comment: Instructions to increase memory easily - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69653948/1205871

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[update] As one commenter suggested, this should no longer be an issue, as firebase functions now maintain their settings on re-deploy. Thanks firebase!

Turns out, and this is not obvious or documented, you can increase the memory allocation to your functions in the [Google Functions Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions). You can also increase the timeout for long-running functions. It solved the problem with memory overload and everything is working great now.

Edit: Note that Firebase will reset your default values on deploy, so you should remember to login to the console and update them right away. I am still looking around for a way to update these settings via CLI, will update when I find it.

Comment: I couldn't find the place to increase the memory allocation for my functions. Where should I go in the functions console? tks!

Comment: @Walucas Cloud Functions > {name of your function} > Click "Edit" > then edit the number in "memory allocation"

Comment: Function settings are getting reset again for me.

Comment: How does adding more memory impact on price?

Comment: You can also set timeout and memory [programmatically](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation).

Answer (score 74):

You can set this from within your Cloud Function file on Firebase.

```
const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 300,
  memory: '1GB'
}

exports.myStorageFunction = functions
  .runWith(runtimeOpts)
  .storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize((object) = > {
    // do some complicated things that take a lot of memory and time
  });
```

**Taken from the docs here:**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation

Don't forget to then run `firebase deploy` from your terminal.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer for consistency. People are answering with command line, not good if you're in a group project or the project shifts.

Comment: import { VALID_MEMORY_OPTIONS } from 'firebase-functions'; `VALID_MEMORY_OPTIONS['1GB']` for typescript

Comment: this should be the best answer, this is the easiest,  future proof, require no maintenance, do and forget approach

Comment: didn't work for me unless I also follow the answer given by @p3sn

Answer (score 67):

I was lost in the UI, couldn't find any option to change the memory, but finally found it:

1. Go to the Google Cloud Platform Console (not the Firebase console)
2. Select [Cloud Functions](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list) in the menu
3. Now you see your firebase function in here if it's correct. Otherwise check if you selected the right project.
4. Ignore all checkboxes, buttons and menu items, just click on the **name of the function**.
5. Click on edit (top menu) and only change the allocated memory and click save.

Comment: Which "top menu"?  I only see "Create Function", "Refresh" , "Delete" and "Copy". Maybe it has to be a paid account?

Comment: You are a life saver! That functions console in google cloud is super awesome!

Comment: Be careful, these settings will be reset to every time you deploy your functions. Use functions.runWith({}). https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation

Comment: Then it forces me to click "next", and then I have to specify a "source code". That doesn't make sense to me. I already uploaded the source code for this function. Why do I have to specify another one and which one tells it to just use what it originally was?

Answer (score 13):

The latest firebase deploy command does overwrite the memory allocation to default 256MB and timeout up to 60s.

Alternatively , to specify the desired memory allocation and maximum timeout , I use gcloud command such as:

**gcloud beta functions deploy *YourFunctionName* --memory=2048MB --timeout=540s**

Other options, please refer to:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy

Answer (score 11):

You can adjust your memory here:

[image]

Comment: This is the only solution that actually works! The UI doesn't allow you to change memory anymore. It seems like it does, but then it requires you to hit the "next" button instead of "save" button. The only way to "save" your memory changes is then to upload new source code for your function which of course makes no sense since the source code of your function already exists or else the function wouldn't be in the table in the first place.

Comment: This is the only and the best solution by far in 2020.

Answer (score 9):

**Figuring out from UI is a bit tricky so here are some guided screenshots:**
Go to url https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

### You can also increase default timeout of 60 sec

[image]

[image]

Comment: This isn't working anymore as its asking to upload the source code again!

Comment: yeah why does it ask for and require another source code just to change memory usage; doesn't it already have the source code uploaded from firebase deploy??? This makes no sense!

Answer (score 5):

Update: It looks that they now preserve settings on re-deploy so you can safely change memory allocation in cloud console!

Comment: Oh, good news! I haven't re-reployed for a while, to avoid anything breaking down. Will give it a try on a test project. It's great if it's working again!

Comment: Update: it's resetting them every time for me (and failing to deploy because the memory limit is exceeded _at deploy time_, which creates an awkward chicken and egg problem).

Comment: As of Jan 2020 the settings are still preserved on re-deploy

Answer (score 5):

you can add the configurations in your firebase functions definitions something like:

```
functions.runWith({memory: '2GB', timeoutSeconds: '360'})
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the default ImageMagick resource config in Firebase Cloud Functions doesn't match the actual memory allocated to the function.

Running `identify -list resource` in the context of a Firebase Cloud Function yields:

```
File       Area         Memory        Map       Disk   Thread  Throttle       Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 18750    4.295GB       2GiB       4GiB  unlimited        8         0   unlimited
```

The default memory allocated to a FCF is 256MB  - the default ImageMagick instance thinks it has 2GB and therefore doesn't allocate buffer from disk and can easily try to over allocate memory causing the function to fail on `Error: memory limit exceeded. Function killed.`

One way is to increase required memory as suggested above - although there's still risk IM will try to over allocate depending on your use case and outliers.

Safer yet would be to set the correct memory limit to IM as part of the image manipulation process using `-limit memory [your limit]`. You can figure out your approx memory usage by running your IM logic with `-debug Cache' - it will show you all the buffers allocated, their sizes and if they were memory or disk.

If IM hits the memory limit it will start allocating buffers on disk (memory mapped and then regular disk buffers.You'll have to consider your specific balance between I/O performance vs memory cost. Price of every additional byte of memory you allocate to your FCF is multiplied by 100ms of usage - so that can grow quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Another option here would be to avoid using `.spawn()` altogether.

There is a great image processing package for node called [Sharp](http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/) that uses the low-memory footprint library [libvips](https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips).  You can check out the Cloud Function sample on [Github](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/image-sharp).

Alternately, there is a Node wrapper for ImageMagick (and GraphicsMagick) called [gm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm).  It even supports the [-limit](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#limit) option to report your resource limitations to IM.

Comment: Interesting. Will give sharp a shot. The problem with Google Cloud is that you can't really test any thing locally, and requires pushing every change through a piece of cloud code. So switching cost is high, even when a better solution.

Comment: You should check out some of the new local testing features that were just added. Now you test triggered functions locally and run unit test on them. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_storage_and_auth_functions

Comment: Emulators don't support storage apis yet