# Function failed on loading user code."memory limit exceeded". (Angular serverside rendering)

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, server-side-rendering

Currently, I'm working on an angular project. I've done serverside rendering by referring to this tutorial [Firebase SSR tutorial](https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-universal-firebase/). I successfully completed it until the second last step. But when I run firebase deploy command it returns an error like this.

> Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: memory
>   limit exceeded.

I tried by updating firebase functions etc... nothing works for me.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to set a higher memory allocation for your function? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation

Comment: @LundinCast I saw this , but i don't know where to use this :( .

Comment: I was checking this on other posts and found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313251/cloud-functions-for-firebase-killed-due-to-memory-limit-exceeded

Check if you can change the memory as it is explained there so that we/you can check if this is a solution and submit it as an answer so that we can help the community (just to help other with the same error)